# Google Picker [gapi.load('picker')] load throws previously unthrown error

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-picker, google-api-js-client

We load the Google API and picker in a similar way to the example provided on [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/)

We include the script in our html like:

```
<script id="scripty" type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

And then in our js:

```
$('#scripty').load(function () {
  console.log('loaded');
  window.gapi && gapi.load('picker', { callback: () => {
    console.log('loaded picker');
    // excluded logic here.
  }});
});
```

We've had this bit of code live and in production for 6+ months now, but only recently (past few days) it has started throwing the following error on console:

```
api.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: _.Rp is not a function
    at https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.npUTEjvGP7I.O/m…=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCO-cN8Rg66fl-34jwiyTEAP1SGPAA/cb=gapi.loaded_1:8:501
    at https://apis.google.com/js/api.js:8:214
    at X (https://apis.google.com/js/api.js:11:220)
    at qa (https://apis.google.com/js/api.js:8:154)
    at W (https://apis.google.com/js/api.js:10:155)
    at b (https://apis.google.com/js/api.js:10:381)
    at Array.Y.r.(anonymous function) (https://apis.google.com/js/api.js:10:485)
    at Object.Y.x.(anonymous function) [as loaded_1] (https://apis.google.com/js/api.js:11:38)
    at https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.npUTEjvGP7I.O/m…d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCO-cN8Rg66fl-34jwiyTEAP1SGPAA/cb=gapi.loaded_1:1:15
```

And the global `google` (window.google) variable no longer loads into place. We've checked out extremely old code to ensure it's nothing that we've changed, and can confirm something changed with the Google API. Has anybody run into this issue?

(see attached image for full error details)[image]

Comment: Haven't seen anything like it before. Was there any change at all on your side within the time that this error started? Is the error *exactly* the same every time? How is the picker being used here? Does the error occur before loading the window or after picking a file?